# How to change local variable value to global value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I just want to change the value of local variable `a` to the value of global variable `a`.

> How to change this `a = 0`  to  `a = 1`?

```
a = 0

 def accurx(a):
    a = a
    return a

 accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar("value a=0 changed to a=1 here", accurx(a))

 def do_report():

    global a
    a = 1
    a = accurx(a)

    summaryx, _ = sess.run([accuracy_summary, correct], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0})
    summaryx_writer.add_summary(summaryx, batch_idx)
```

> i calling accuracy_summary here

Comment: You can achieve this through global keyword ( which you are anyways doing within do_report() function.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the good way but you function `accurx` seems to be useless, `a = 1` is already modifying the value of `a`

If you want to modify a local value with a global value, don't name it the same way to be clear

Do it this way

```
a = 0

def do_report():

    global a
    a = 1

do_report()

accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar("value a=0 changed to a=1 here", a)

summaryx, _ = sess.run([accuracy_summary, correct], feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0})
summaryx_writer.add_summary(summaryx, batch_idx)
```

Comment: after all a is still 0 in accuracy_summary

Comment: yes, you are not calling your `do_report` function, the code is just doing `a = a` and `return a` so `0 = 0`, `return 0`

Comment: so where i call do_report?

Comment: is there any other way to not calling do_report before accuracy_summary and change a value 0 to 1 ?

Comment: You can't modify the value with do_report without calling it, you need to do this way (I added two print to show you the value from 0 to 1)
`a = 0

def do_report():

    global a
    a = 1

print(a)
do_report()
print(a)`